# does SMTP Authentication with an app password on Office 365 require a connector?

Tags: python, office365, smtplib

We recently enabled MFA on our account that sends out automated emails to staff/clients, so obviously we need a new way to authenticate that process. OAuth seems like overkill, so I went the "app password" route, which I've done seamlessly through services like Gmail.

But this just isn't working... I get the following error:

**smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [CH0PR03CA0182.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]')**

Note that SMTP Authentication is turned on and I'm using STARTTLS 1.2. I've seen people pass parameters like:

```
SMTPSecure: 'tls'
SMTPAuth: true;
```

...but I don't know if that's needed for this, since it was working fine before the MFA switch. I also don't know where/how to send those with smtplib

Does anyone have any advice? I'm told I might need an SMTP Connector? Which also seems like an overcomplication of the process and wasn't mentioned in any MS article that instructed users on setting up app passwords. My code is below, fwiw. I haven't changed ANY of it since turning on MFA:

```
def send_mail(recipients: str, subject: str, body: str, attachments: list = None, cc: str = None):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    smtp_srv_name = "smtp.office365.com"
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_srv_name, 587)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    msg['To'] = recipients
    msg['Cc'] = cc
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    if attachments is not None:
        for attachment in attachments:
            with open(attachment, 'rb') as attachment_fileobject:
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload(attachment_fileobject.read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', f"attachment; filename={Path(attachment).name}")
                msg.attach(part)
    smtp_server.starttls()
    smtp_server.login('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', mc_decrypt(credentials['notices_email_pw'], CRYPT_KEY))
    smtp_server.send_message(msg)
    smtp_server.close()
```

Answer (score 9):

Fixed it. All I had to do was disable Azure Security Defaults. The suggestion was in a MS support article that apparently isn't indexed on Google... so here's the content:

**SMTP Authentication issues for Microsoft 365 Mailbox**

If you are getting "Client not authenticated", "Authentication unsuccessful" OR "SmtpClientAuthentication" error with code 5.7.57 or 5.7.3 or 5.7.139 when trying to send email by authenticating a device or application with Microsoft 365, there are following three things you should perform to make it work:

1. Enable Client SMTP submission on the licensed mailbox being used-

Run the following Powershell command-
Set-CASMailbox -Identity sean@contoso.com -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false

Or

From Microsoft 365 Admin Center, go to Active Users and select the user
Go to Mail tab
In the “Email apps” section, click on “Manage email apps”
Verify the “Authenticated SMTP” setting is checked (enabled)
Click Save changes.

2. Disable the Azure Security Defaults by toggling the “Enable Security Defaults” to “No”.

Sign in to the Azure portal as a security administrator, Conditional Access administrator, or global administrator.
Browse to Azure Active Directory > Properties.
Select Manage security defaults.
Set the Enable security defaults toggle to No.
Select Save.

3. Disable Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) on the licensed mailbox being used -

In the Microsoft 365 Admin Center, in the left navigation menu choose Users > Active users.
On the Active users page, choose Multi-factor authentication.
On the multi-factor authentication page, select the user and disable the Multi-Factor auth status.

Comment: I haven't done much admin work with Microsoft stuff in years. It's incredible how disconnected all their admin panels feel these days. Azure admin, Exchange admin, Office admin, etc etc. Good god, what a convoluted mess.

Comment: To disable "Azure Security Defaults". Azure Active Directory is now called Microsoft Entra ID. There you have to go to Identity > Overview > Properties and then at the bottom of the page: Security defaults

Comment: "All I had to do was disable Azure Security Defaults" – Is there no other option? I'm not comfortable with disabling Security Defaults for my (very) non-tech-savvy users.